# Regex compare a word with space before and after

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an array of string the store the user input in, and I want to check if the input user contains only the specific word `END` only, and I don't mind if there are any space before the word or after the word for example the user could input the word like `END` or "END   " or  "   END  " or "   END". I don't really care how many space there are before or after the word I just want to check that the input string contains ONLY the word `END` without taking the spaces into consideration.

I tried

```
Regex regex_ending_char = new Regex(@"^END|^\s+END$|^END+\s$");
// to compare the word "END" only nothing before it nor after it - 
// space is of anywhere before or after the word

Match Char_Instruction_match = regex_ending_char.Match(Instruction_Separator[0]);
if (!Char_Instruction_match.Success) // True if word doesn't end with "END"
{
    richTextBox2.Text += "Error in line " + (LineNumber + 1) + ",  Code must end with 'END'" + Environment.NewLine;
}`
```

I also tried

```
Regex regex_ending_char = new Regex(@"^END|^\s+END$|^END+\s$"); 
// to compare the word "END" only nothing before it nor after 
// it - space is of anywhere before or after the word

Regex.Replace(Instruction_Separator[0], @"\s+", "");
Match Char_Instruction_match = regex_ending_char.Match(Instruction_Separator[0]);
if (!Char_Instruction_match.Success) // True if word doesn't end with "END"
{
    richTextBox2.Text += "Error in line " + (LineNumber + 1) + ",  Code must end with 'END'" + Environment.NewLine;
}`
```

the problem is that I have to only check the first element of the array `Instruction_Separator[0]` and not any other element. So if the user inputs a space before the word `END` like so " END" then the `Instruction_Separator` array becomes `Instruction_Separator[0] = " ", Instruction_Separator[1] = END` and therefore there the code goes to the if condition even though the user input the correct string he only input a space at the beginning which I have no problem with if there is a space before or after the word.

Thanks you everyone for your response, I respect all of your answers. What I'm trying to do is to build an assembler and I have to check for syntax error and comments are okay in the user input. SO for example if the user input was as follows:

```
ORG 100 //Begin at memory location 100
LDA A // Load A
A, DEC 83 // A has a decimal value of 83
END // End the code
```

then there are aren't any syntax error and I could give a result.

Also if the user added spaces before each line, that's fine as well

```
ORG 100 //Begin at memory location 100
    LDA A // Load A
    A, DEC 83 // A has a decimal value of 83
         END // End the code
```

so I want to check each line if it contains the correct syntax or not and I don't really care about any spaces before or after the correct format of each line.

A user syntax error would be something like:

```
OR G 100 //Begin at memory location 100
LDA A // Load A
A, DEC 83 // A has a decimal value of 83
EN  To end the code
```

notice that ORG is written "OR G" which is wrong, also END is written "EN" and the user forgot to place "//" before the comment "End the code"

So What I need to do is to check that the last line contains the word "END" and if there is "//" then whats after it is a comment. But the user must type "//" if he wants to add a comment to a line. It's of if he doesn't want to add a comment it's not a must. Any idea how I can do this using regex as I mentioned above I tried `Regex regex_ending_char = new Regex(@"^END|^\s+END$|^END+\s$");` but I didn't seem to work correct

Thanks in advance looking forward for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

I also wouldn't use Regex. In fact:

```
bool b = input.Trim() == "END"
```

Could work too! If by "spaces" you also want to include other whitespace.

Otherwise:

```
bool b = input.Replace(" ", "") == "END"
```

But, I guess if you absolutely *have* to have a regex in there... try:

```
^\s*END\s*(//.*)?$
```

To be used as:

```
Regex regex_ending_char = new Regex(@"^\s*END\s*(//.*)?$");
```

So what is going on there? It is all just absolute basic regex...

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace
- `END` matches the desired string "END"
- `\s*` you can have whitespace after if you like...
- `(//.*)?` matches an optional group of two slashes followed by zero or more characters
- `$` matches the end of the string

Comment: Thanks buddy,
I'll try it right away and I'll inform you with the updates

Comment: I tried it but there seem to be a problem, I'm sorry I'm new to regex and I'm trying to understand it as we go along.

Regex regex_ending_char = new Regex(@"^\s*END\s*(//.*)?$");

Comment: so what is the problem? with which input did it not match?

Answer (score 1):

**updated the answer according to the edits in question**

You don't still need regex. It can be done with basic string operations.

```
bool b = input.Split(new string[] { "//" },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Trim() == "END";
```

Comment: But also +meh for not using `Trim()`.

Comment: @Dialecticus do you think it needs Trim?

Comment: Need more information to answer that question. If `input` is basis for `Instruction_Separator` I would like to see how `Instruction_Separator` is formed. One `Trim` there could solve more than one problem.

Answer (score 0):

Again, a good example where using regular expression is a bad idea. This requirement can simply be fullfilled with this code:

```
var stringToTest = "Something that ends with END  ";
var valid = stringToTest
    .TrimEnd(' ')
    .EndsWith("END", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as you can see in my above question as I edited is that I want to check each line for special words! any idea?

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex:

```
bool ok = input.Trim() == "END";
```